# how to fix this easy digital communication excercise using MATLAB

Tags: function, communication, matlab, bit

I have a problem in writing in MATLAB a program that modulates data bits, adds noise then demodulates it and calculate the bit error and the symbol error rate. The modulation used first should be QPSK. I have done the following,

```
    N=100;
    databits = randi([0 3],N,1);
    hModulator = comm.QPSKModulator;
    hModulator.PhaseOffset = pi/4;
    txsig = step(hModulator, databits);
    scatterplot(txsig)
    grid on
    SNRdB=-10
    rxsig = awgn(txsig,SNRdB);
    H = comm.QPSKDemodulator
    hH.PhaseOffset = pi/4;
    symdecoded=step(H,rxsig)
    symerr(symdecoded,databits)
    biterr(symdecoded, databits)
```

My first question is I don't think I am doing the bit error rate and symbol error rate correctly, can someone help me spot where the problem is? Where am I missing out?

I am then asked to repeat the same problem but make the changes needed to make it work with 16-QAM and 64-QAM by changing a parameter called CONSTELLATION.

I have tried using demod and ddemodce but these two functions are removed from matlab? Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are using SNRdB=-10 dB?
Try for example positive numbers 0 10 20 30, and you may save symerr and biterr as the function proposes [number,ratio] = symerr(x,y)
number= numb of error and ratio = bitsTx/bitsRx
For m-qam better use modem.qammod try the help in matlab

Best regards and good luck